# How to callback to code behind in custom control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using wpf. I created a custom control. In this control, I have multiple buttons. I can bind the button commands to the viewmodel. In this application, however, I need to callback to the code back file and not the viewmdoel. How can I do that?

Here is the example of my custom control:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
        <Button Content="Button A" Command="{Binding SwitchToABCCommand}">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurRegion}" Value="ABC">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Button B" Command="{Binding SwitchToEFGCommand}">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurRegion}" Value="DEF">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then I have another window using this custom control.

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand SwitchToABCCommand { get; }
public ICommand SwitchToDEFCommand { get; }
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    SwitchToABCCommand = new DelegateCommand(HandleSwitchToABCCommand);
    SwitchToEFGCommand = new DelegateCommand(HandleSwitchToEFGCommand);
}
private void HandleSwitchToABCCommand()
{

}
private void HandleSwitchToDEFCommand()
{

}
```

And I want to callback to MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void SwitchToABC(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
private void SwitchToDEF(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I have tried to do:

```
<Button Content="Button A" Click="SwitchToABC">
```

But this only can callback to `MyCustomControl.xaml.cs`. How can I call back to MainWindow.xaml.cs ?

Thank you

Comment: So you assume that the control is always being used in the context of a view model which has a `SwitchToABCCommand` or a main window?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to call code behind? Surely main view model would have that functionality. And if you are looking for communication between view models look into a messenger pattern.

Comment: If I've read your requirement properly, you are looking to call back into the code behind of the page from within the control - and you should not do this in the way you're thinking. The control should have no knowledge of the wider environment it is hosted within. However you could declare an event handler (delegate) and invoke that handler/delegate if it is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler must be defined in the same class as the XAML markup. If you define `SwitchToABC` in `MyCustomControl.xaml.cs`, you can call an event handler from the `MainWindow` from there though:

```
private void SwitchToABC(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    if (parentWindow != null)
    {
        parentWindow.SomeHandler(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Note that this create a strong coupling between the control and the window.

Binding to a `SwitchToABCCommand` command in the control XAML also creates an indirect coupling to the view model. A better way would be to add a command property to the control and bind this one to the view model command property, e.g.:

```
<MyCustomControl YourCommand="{Binding SwitchToABCCommand }"  />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For the property method, I will search for information first. I am not sure how to bind the `YourCommand` to the button in my `StackPanel`, since I have multiple buttons.